# Using uint array as an argument in Solidity function

Tags: remix

I am trying to compile following on Remix IDE:

```
 pragma solidity ^0.5.1;
 contract testArray{
    address addr;
    function testA(uint _addr, uint[] emp) public{
       addr = _addr;
       for(uint i=0; i<emp.length; ++i){
          addr.send(emp[i].value);
      }
   }
}
```

I am getting following error:

> browser/arr.sol:4:31: TypeError: Data location must be "memory" for parameter in function, but none was given.
>   function testA(uint _addr, uint[] emp) public{
>   ^--------^
>   Somebody please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In solidity 0.5.x you need to specify the memory location of parameters, and whether or not address variables are payable.

The below should work:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.1;
contract testArray {
    address payable addr;
    function testA(address payable _addr, uint[] memory emp) public{
        addr = _addr;
        for(uint i=0; i<emp.length; ++i){
            addr.send(emp[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: browser/arr.sol:7:13: Warning: Failure condition of 'send' ignored. Consider using 'transfer' instead.
addr.send(emp[i]);
^---------------^
It gives me a warning. I tried transfer, it worked. Good. Leaving 'send' as it is should not be a problem for execution?

Comment: As per the error, if you're using `send` you should pay attention to its failure condition - it will return `false` rather than reverting like `transfer` does if the operation fails.

Comment: Is memory directive necessary only for array or even for simple variables i.e. non array variables